# How do I call JSON in a simplified manner

Tags: c#

I am connecting to an external API which seems to be returning JSON

```
using (var client = new APIClient())
{
    var data = client.General.GetAccountInfo().Data.Balances;
}
```

When I move over `.Data.Balances`, it shows:

```
IEnumerable<API.Net.Objects.Spot.SpotData.APIBalance>
API.Net.Objects.Spot.SpotData.APIAccountInfo.Balances { get; set; }

List of assets and their current balances
```

Here is an extract of the JSON data:

```
"balances":[
   {
      "asset":"ABC",
      "free":"0.00000000",
      "locked":"0.00000000"
   },
   {
      "asset":"DEF",
      "free":"0.00000000",
      "locked":"0.00000000"
   },
   {
      "asset":"GHI",
      "free":"0.00000000",
      "locked":"0.00000000"
   }
]
```

How do I make use of this data so if I type `console.writeline(data[0]["asset"])`, it gives me `ABC`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the simplist solution:

```
using System.Linq;

using (var client = new APIClient())
{
    var data = client.General.GetAccountInfo().Data.Balances.ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(data[0].asset);
    Console.WriteLine(data[0].free);
    Console.WriteLine(data[0].locked);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hy,
From the sample file you can create a class ´balance »
Public class balance
{
Public string asset {get; set;}
Public  Free .......
Public    Locked .....
}

And then you can use Json.net
To deserialize the JSon file
public void serializejson()
{
List balances =         JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List>(data);
}
}

Comment: You probably mean newtonsoft... maybe add the nuget link

Answer (score -1):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace Game
{
    public class Balance
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("asset")]
        public string Asset { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("free")]
        public string Free { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("locked")]
        public string Locked { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("balances")]
        public List<Balance> Balances { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = File.ReadAllText("test.json");

            var deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(data); 
            
            var balances = deserialized.Balances;

            // Don't iterati in such a way! Use foreach instead.
            for (int i = 0; i < balances.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{balances[i].Asset} {balances[i].Free} {balances[i].Locked}");
            }

            foreach (var balance in balances)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{balance.Asset} {balance.Free} {balance.Locked}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this code for you:

```
    public class Balance    {
        public string asset { get; set; } 
        public string free { get; set; } 
        public string locked { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Root    {
        public List<Balance> balances { get; set; } 
    }
```

And for deserialize:

```
using (var client = new APIClient())
{
    var data = client.General.GetAccountInfo().Data.Balances;
    Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(data); 
    Console.WriteLine(myDeserializedClass.balances[0].asset);
}
```